# Create MySQL Database AND Grant Privileges simultaneously

Tags: mysql

Problem: I have a program that backs-up databases by creating a copy of a live database and then epoch time stamps it.

```
query = `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDb-${dateStamp} `;
```

When I later try to delete that newly created database with the same credentials as used to create it result is `Access denied for user`.

Is there a query that can do the following?

- create a `table \ Schema` with a user account
- simultaneously give full privileges to the creating user
- creating user does not have root MySQL privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable multi query and write them all in your query variable. separated by semicolon, that will execute them sequentially. but never simultaneous

```
query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDb-${dateStamp};  GRANT ALL ON  myDb-${dateStamp}.* TO 'ROOT'@'localhost'; CREATE USER 'TESTUSER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my-strong-password-h'; GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, DROP, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON  myDb-${dateStamp}.* TO 'TESTUSER'@'localhOST'; USE myDb-${dateStamp}; CREATE TABLE Tablex SELECT * FROM Table1;"
```

And so on.

Mysql doesn't mind a singe query or multiple, as long the basic language like php can handles multi querys.

Or you do them one by one